# collection_check_boxes = collection_check_boxes

Tags: javascript, jquery, ruby-on-rails, ruby, ajax

If a user checks or unchecks a `:committed` day how can we automatically match `send_email`'s `collection_check_boxes` to whatever is presently checked or unchecked in `:committed` `collection_check_boxes`?

For example if a user checks "sun" and unchecks "fri" in `committed` then those changes would also be reflected in `:send_email`.

[image]

But not vice versa.

For example if a user changes the checked days of `send_email` then no javascript should take effect. `:committed` should only change upon direct contact.

[image]

```
<%= f.collection_check_boxes :committed, Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES, :downcase, :to_s, checked: ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri"] %>

<%= f.collection_check_boxes :send_email, Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES, :downcase, :to_s, checked: ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri"] %>

<script>
</script>
```

Thanks javascript friends!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Assuming each collection of checkboxes will have the same value (Monday and Monday), you could group each collection of checkboxes in a div.

```
<div class="committed-check-boxes">
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :committed, Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES, :downcase, :to_s, checked: ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri"] %>
</div>

<div class="send-email-check-boxes">
  <%= f.collection_check_boxes :send_email, Date::ABBR_DAYNAMES, :downcase, :to_s, checked: ["mon", "tue", "wed", "thu", "fri"] %>
</div>
```

Only listen for clicks from the `.committed-check-boxes` div. Find the matching checkbox from `.send-email-check-boxes` and use `prop` to set checked to true/false.

```
<script>
  $('.committed-check-boxes input[type="checkbox"]').on('click', function() {
    var checkbox = $(this);

    $('.send-email-check-boxes')
      .find('input[value="' + checkbox.val() + '"]')
      .prop('checked', checkbox.prop('checked'));
  });
</script>
```